# Annotations are not allowed here

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, annotations, spring-data-jpa

I'm creating a UserRepository which implements JpaRepository and works with User entity. I need a method to update username. I decided to do it with the help of @Query. But it's marked by Intellij. Here is my code for repository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

@Modifying
@Query(value = "update User user set user.name= %?username"))
void updatingUser(@Param(value = "username") String username);
}
```

And for Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "user_id")
private Long id;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "user_name")
private String username;
}
```

And I faced with such a problem: "Annotations are not allowed here" says Intellij Idea and marks the line with @Query annotation. And it made me confused

Answer (score 127):

In my case, I accidentally typed ";" at the end of @Query. Might help someone else.

Comment: i made the same mistake, removed ; and now code compiled successfully.

Comment: for me it was forgetting to add () to my method signature

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I had the same mistake, a semicolon at the end of line just out of habit.

Comment: Glad I came here because that was gonna confuse me for a while. Love coming to stack overflow to find out I'm just regular dumb and not even complicated dumb.

Comment: Turns out I did the same despite staring at it for quite sometime. Thanks for posting this as it may have taken me a lot longer to spot if not for your comment.

Answer (score 14):

Sorry, guys. It was so stupid for me to write double quotes in the end of this line. But I actually don't understand why Intellij didn't notice that but started to mark this line with another mistake

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I accidently typed an ';' at the end of the @Query sentence.

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM Author a")
@QueryHints(value = @QueryHint(name = HINT_FETCH_SIZE, value= "" + Integer.MIN_VALUE));
Stream<Author> streamAll();
```

After I removed the ';' from the @QueryHints, then it worked perfectly.

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM Author a")
@QueryHints(value = @QueryHint(name = HINT_FETCH_SIZE, value= "" + Integer.MIN_VALUE))
Stream<Author> streamAll();
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry this was 4 years too late, but you have an extra ')' at the end of your @Query line

Answer (score 0):

Using the `@Query` annotation in this place is absolutely appropriate. But your query is not quite correct.

Query parameters can be named - ':name' or indexed - '?1'.

You should use update queries with 'where' clause otherwise you will update all records.

You code should be like this:

```
@Modifying
@Query("update User u set u.name = ?1 where u.name = ?2")
void updateByName(String value, String name);
```

Or like this:

```
@Modifying
@Query("update User u set u.name = :value where u.name = :name")
void updateByName(@Param("value") String value, @Param("name") String name);
```

Pay attention - while the 'name' field is not unique you will update ALL users with given 'name'. To update only one user you must use unique field or primary key in the 'where' clause, for example:

```
@Modifying
@Query("update User u set u.name = ?1 where u.id = ?2")
void updateById(String value, Long id);
```

By the way if you need to update all user which have specific name pattern - use 'like' operator:

```
@Modifying
@Query("update User u set u.name = ?1 where u.name like '%'||?2||'%'")
void updateByNameLike(String value, String name);
```

Useful info:

[Spring Data JPA - Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/)

[JPQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_04/ejb3_langref.html)

[SQL Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp)

P.S. Annotation `@Repository` is not necessary

Comment: Thanks, I've corrected it. Now my query looks like this.  
    Modifying
    Query(value = "update com.ranv.Model.ModelDB.User u set  u.username = ?1 where u.id = ?2")
    void updatingUser( String username, Long id);   Butnow there is the other problem: class User is not an Entity. But actually it is (Entity annotation is on it's place as you can see in my code above)

Comment: @Andrey-2310 Check imports. I think you set a wrong one. (And don't forget that 'thanks' here is equal to 'accept/upvote the answer'..)

Comment: but this object is exactly what I need. It represents my entity.

Comment: Ok. I've answered on your first question?

Comment: @ Cepr0, Yeah, sure. by the way the answer on my second question is adding Hibernate and JPA modules

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got this issue with the following query after copying from SQLyog.

```
SELECT  id FROM (SELECT * FROM departments ORDER BY id) dpt_sorted, (SELECT @pv := '2') initialisation WHERE   FIND_IN_SET(parent_dept, @pv) AND LENGTH(@pv := CONCAT(@pv, ',', id));
```

But when i typed the query, the error message disappeared. May be `copy` and `paste` issue in my case. This could be helpful.